# some products are not viewable and not able to add into shopping cart

Tags: product, url, url-rewrite

i have a product e.g

http://example.com/au/catalog/product/view/id/769 (also not viewable by using
Request Path e.g productname.html)

it redirects me to no-route

http://example.com/au/no-route

anyone knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

That one can have many causes, most common:

1. product is not enabled
2. product visibility is set to "not visible individually"
3. product is set at "out of stock" and the "Display Out of Stock Products" configuration is set to no (or, for bundles, one of the components is out of stock)
4. product is not in a category and your site's setup only shows categorised product

If none of them are the case, kick caches and indexes

If that still doesn't work, sometimes changing enabled/disabled and in stock/out of stock back and forth can help, as can taking it out and back in a category (that is in the "weird bug" category)

Update: your example URL has a **"store view"** path /au/ in it - this brings me to

1. your product has one of more of 1-4 for the particular storeview in question

Update: **multi country/region set up**

Not knowing how much is customised on your site, I would start to look at what is different in each "scope" store / store view (you get a drop down on the top left to switch from website level to store/store view)

If it is just the one or the other products, others are fine, then it is probably an attribute issue. One that needs to be set correctly for the product to show.

1. Look at your attributes table and see which ones are set to be at the store or store view level, to get started. Any "global" one will not be the problem
2. look at your category tree. Sometimes it is a totally different tree per store and if your product is not in one of them, there will be no route to the product
3. Look at your configuration especially the "catalogue" area, "general" area (currency) and the sales area (tax).
4. check settings around enabled, visibility (are they different per store view?)
5. settings around stock (are they different per store or store view, and is the "display out of stock" different?)
6. missing core fields, such as description, short description, price, for the particular store/store view (if they are not set to global)

Much more messy: check your country tax zone and tax rules settings, and that the tax class this product is in is appearing in rules for Australia... A product in a tax class which is not associated to a particular country might not show in that country (or it could show but not be buyable, I haven't messed with this for a while)

Also, settings around currency/price if you have enabled multi currency. A product which does not have a price might not show

Comment: thanks for your answer, the product in asia store view can be added into cart but Australia store view can't, why is the most possible to cause this?

Comment: Editing the main answer - still focused on visibility first

For add to cart: stock, tax class (and the tax rules behind it), price (and currency) all can matter.